# Problems creating a custom controller for Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am porting a native Android app to Xamarin + MVVMCross.  On my Native Android app I was easily able to create my custom DateDisplayPicker and use it.  I'm having trouble in Xamarin.  My control lives here:

[image: here]

My DateDisplayPicker.cs looks like so:

```
namespace XxxxXxxx.Droid.CustomViews
{
    public class DateDisplayPicker : TextView, DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
    {
        private readonly Context context;
        private readonly Calendar calendar;

        protected DateDisplayPicker(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public DateDisplayPicker(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public DateDisplayPicker(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        this.context = context;
        SetAttributes();
        this.calendar = Calendar.Instance;
    }

    public DateDisplayPicker(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            this.context = context;
            calendar = Calendar.Instance;
        }

        private void SetAttributes()
        {
            Click += (sender, args) => ShowDateDialog();
        }

        private void ShowDateDialog()
        {
            var c = Calendar.Instance;
            var dp = new DatePickerDialog(context, this, c.Get(CalendarField.Year),
                c.Get(CalendarField.Month), c.Get(CalendarField.DayOfMonth));
            dp.Show();
        }

        public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            Text = String.Format("%s/%s/%s", monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth, year);
            calendar.Set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        }

        public void AddDay()
        {
            calendar.Add(CalendarField.Date, 1);
            Text = String.Format("%s/%s/%s", calendar.Get(CalendarField.Month) + 1,
                calendar.Get(CalendarField.DayOfMonth), calendar.Get(CalendarField.Year));
        }

        public void SubtractDay()
        {
            calendar.Add(CalendarField.Date, -1);
            Text = String.Format("%s/%s/%s", calendar.Get(CalendarField.Month) + 1,
                calendar.Get(CalendarField.DayOfMonth), calendar.Get(CalendarField.Year));
        }

        public string GetDate()
        {
            var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
            return sdf.Format(calendar.Time);
        }
    }
}
```

And them I'm accessing it in my Android fragment like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            <com.workspace.xxxxxxxx.droid.customviews.DateDisplayPicker
                android:id="@+id/managerDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="XX-XX-XXXX"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner"
                android:hint="Date" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/managerDateMinusButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/managerDate"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/button_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/minus"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/managerDatePlusButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/managerDate"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/plus"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/managerExpandableListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:stackFromBottom="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assignedMessageText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No tasks today."
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@id/progressBar1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

From the few examples I've seen this is pretty much how they've been set up but I must be missing something.  Any ideas?  I've confirmed my namespace for the control in the axml is all lowercase.  When my application errors out I get:

```
Pending exception is:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.workspace.xxxxxxxx.droid.customviews.DateDisplayPicker
(raw stack trace not found)
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.workspace.xxxxxxxx.droid.customviews.DateDisplayPicker" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.workspace.xxxxxxxx-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.workspace.xxxxxxxx-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I was just being dumb.  If I leave off the "com." this works so it seems like the lesson learned here is to use **EXACTLY** what the namespace is on the control class, in this case it was "xxxxxxxx.droid.customviews.DateDisplayPicker" in the axml.  Hope this helps anyone else who strugged with this!